# How to add footnote to table text multiple times

Tags: tables, footnotes

I am using `\tablefootnote`. I need to attribute one footnote multiple times that's why I used `label` inside the `\tablefootnote`. The problem is that the footnote does not appear in the same page of the table. In the original document, it appears in the next page and in this example, it appears in the previous page. I need a solution either in this script or provide me with another simple solution.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE

  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{colortbl}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\lipsum
\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{mytable}
\label{table:mytable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ cccc}
\toprule
&   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5ex]{A}}
&   AAA & BBB & CCC \\
\midrule
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text1\tablefootnote{\label{note1}footnote} &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
Text2\textsuperscript{\ref{note1}} &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\lipsum
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've done this using `threeparttable` but don't have the code to hand. Is that an option for you? I seem to recall some hand-coding of the footnotes.

Comment: @Chris H yes please post the code if it will solve the problem.

Comment: I'll try to remember tomorrow when I'm in front of a computer with it on

Comment: My old code and a simpler example are up now.  I'm not sure how close it is to what you're looking for

Comment: @user6875880 Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I used a fairly manual approach in the end.  The `\tnote` macro was used to typeset the footnote mark in the table itself, and `\item` with a matching optional argument was used for the actual table notes.

Here's a stripped down example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{A table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline\\
        A column\tnote{a}&another column&column 3\\
        \hline\\
        1\tnote{b}&2&3\\
        4&5\tnote{b}&6\\
        7&8&9\\
        \hline\\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \raggedright
        \item[a] A table note.
        \item[b] A rather longer table note referred to in multiple places.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image: A sample table]

Here's a table from my thesis, tweaked just enough so it compiles on its own (which made some spurious spaces appear before some of the footnote marks):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multicol}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Wmk}{\si{\watt\per\metre\per\kelvin}}
\newcommand*\rfrac[2]{{}^{#1}\!/_{#2}}%running fraction with slash - requires math mode.
\robustify\tnote %for using siunitx and threeparttable
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize} %and for making threeparttable's footnotes footnotesize
\sisetup{tight-spacing=true,scientific-notation=false}%

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption[High\hyp{}frequency\hyp{}related material parameters.]{\label{tab_Theory_Materials}High\hyp{}frequency\hyp{}related material parameters.  Based on a table in reference \emph{dummy}, some data from reference \emph{dummy}.}
    \small{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$E_g$\tnote{a}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$n_i$\tnote{b}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\epsilon_r$\tnote{c}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu_n$\tnote{d}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$v_\mathrm{sat}$\tnote{e}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$E_\mathrm{br}$\tnote{f}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathit{TC}$\tnote{g}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathit{JM}$\tnote{h}}\\
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\eV}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\cm^{-3}}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\cm\per\volt\per\s}}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{$\times 10^7$\si{\cm\per\s}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\si{\mega\volt\per\cm}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{\Wmk}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
        \midrule\\
        Si&1.1&1.5e10&11.8&1350&1.0&0.3&150&1\\
        GaAs&1.42&1.5e5&13.1&8500&1.0&0.6&43&2.7\\
        SiC (4H)&3.26&8.2e-9&10&700&2.0&3.0&450\tnote{~i}&20\\
        GaN&3.4&1.9e-10&9.0&2000\tnote{~j}&2.5&3.3&130&27.5\\
        Diamond&5.4&1.6e-27&5.5&1900&2.7&5.6&2000&50\\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}
        \setlength{\multicolsep}{0cm}
        \begin{multicols}{2}\raggedright
            \item[a] Bandgap.
            \item[b] Intrinsic carrier density at room temperature.
            \item[c] Relative permittivity.
            \item[d] Electron mobility.
            \item[e] Saturation velocity.
            \item[f] Breakdown field. 
            \item[g] Thermal conductivity at room temperature. The thermal conductivity reduces with temperature at typical operating temperatures. For GaN $\mathit{TC}\propto T^{-1.4}$ is often used, though values vary.
            \item[h] Johnson figure of merit, which compares the power\hyp{}frequency performance of materials, normalised to the value for Si. $JM=\rfrac{E_\mathrm{br}v_\mathrm{sat}}{2\pi}$.
            \item[i] In-plane; parallel to the $c$-axis the thermal conductivity is 330~\Wmk.
            \item[j] Within the 2DEG; the bulk value is \SI[scientific-notation=false]{1200}{\cm\per\volt\per\s}.
        \end{multicols}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table based on above code]

If you're using it with `siunitx` I suggest you take a look at the code for the longer example.

Comment: From `three­part­table` manual: 'Note that a `three­part­table` is not a float of it­self; but you can place it in a `ta­ble` or a `ta­ble*` en­vironment, if nec­es­sary.'

Comment: In addition, encapsulating footnotes with `\footnotesize` might be of interest for some: e.g. `\item[a] {\footnotesize Bandgap.}`